# Scheme appending to a list without append?

Tags: scheme, racket

I've been trying to append an s-expression without a using the append operator to a list in scheme. So far I've attempted by having a helper function called 'next-member' that will iterate through to the next item of the list. This may be an elementary recursive problem that I can't get my head wrapped around it since I'm new to Scheme syntax:

```
(define next-member
  (lambda lst
    (cond
      ((not (null? lst)) (car lst))
      (else (next-member (cdr lst)))
      )))

(define append-item
  (lambda (a b)
    (cond
      ((null? b) (list a))
      ((null? a) b)
      (else (list (car b) (next-member (cdr b)) a))
      )))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the syntax that is your problem, it's semantics.

Your first function says "the 'next element' of a non-empty list is its head; the 'next element' of an empty list is the 'next element' of its tail".
This does not make sense – an empty list has no tail (and it's not clear what you expect this function to accomplish).

Your second function says "in order to append `a` to `b`, create a list of three elements: the first element of `b`, the 'next element' of `(cdr b)`, and `a`".

It looks like what you actually want to do is to add a single element at the end of a list.

You can do this with the most basic list-recursion "pattern":

- If the list is empty, do something
- Otherwise, do something involving the head of the list and the result of recursing on its tail.

In your problem, the base case is simple; it is a singleton list of `a`:

```
(define (append-item a bs)
    (if (null? bs)
        (list a)
```

and in order to recurse, you realize that you can achieve the goal by last-appending the element to the tail of `bs` and then add the first element of `bs` to the front:

```
        (cons (car bs) (append-item a (cdr bs)))))
```

As a side note, the traditional name of this functions is `snoc`, which is "cons" backwards.
(On another side note, an "s-expression" is source code; you can't append it to anything.)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any helper function- you need to know function [`cons`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._cons%29%29) and how it's used for creating lists.

Function `cons` call creates one *dotted pair* from two arguments:

```
> (cons 1 2)
'(1 . 2)
```

Second argument can be list, then new list with first argument as first element of that list is returned:

```
> (cons 1 '())
'(1)
> '(1 . ())
'(1)
> (cons 1 '(2 3))
'(1 2 3)
> '(1 . (2 3))
'(1 2 3)
```

Lists are built as chain of `cons` calls, where last element of last pair is empty list:

```
> (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '())))
'(1 2 3)
> '(1 . (2 . (3 . ())))
'(1 2 3)
```

So, imagine solution for this task:

1. If first argument is empty, return second argument.
2. If second argument is empty, return first argument.
3. Else recursively build chain of dotted pairs with elements from first list and when you reach end, put second list on the end. Like this:

```
> (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '(4 5 6))))
'(1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

Whole solution:

```
(define (append-list lst1 lst2)
  (cond ((null? lst1) lst2)
        ((null? lst2) lst1)
        (else (cons (car lst1)
                    (append-list (cdr lst1) lst2)))))
```

Examples:

```
> (append-list '() '(1 2 3))
'(1 2 3)
> (append-list '(1 2 3) '())
'(1 2 3)
> (append-list '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
'(1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

Answer (score 2):

Other way is to define append with mutation (`append!` is called sometimes or sometimes [`nconc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Append#Lisp)).  The idea is to mutate the `cdr` of the last list element to point to the second list instead of pointing to `'()`.

Other way is to [use folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Append#Implementation).

Answer (score 1):

Append isn't a primitive;  `cons` is. You can easily create `append` using `cons`. Here is a straight forward implementation for a two argument version:

```
(define (my-append a b)
  (if (null? a)
      b
      (cons (car a) 
            (my-append (cdr a) b))))
```

`list` as well as rest arguments also uses `cons` under the hood. If it's pairs they are created with `cons` and nothing else!